# What is the longest journey made of 2-hour flights from London?

Tags: air-travel, factoids

Starting from London, what are the furthest places that can be reached by commercial flights, with any number of flight segments and stopovers, but all flights lasting under 2 hours?

For example, can you make it to Shanghai? Tokyo? Sydney? Cape Town? And with what route?

Comment: Are you asking as an academic problem? Or because you have an aversion to long flights? If the latter, we'll have to consider your eligibility for transit visas, and the political risks of entering certain countries.  Also, the fare might be extremely exhorbitant.  A sea trip might be more practical.

Comment: Really curious about that... My former boss has a genetic disease that prevents him from flying more than 6 hours (well he can but needs injections in-flight, which is never pleasant). So he solved the problem by buying a private jet and flying within range of the plane only.

Comment: Interesting question, but why??

Comment: Have you considered walking to your destination instead?

Comment: We're really curious about the reason why you ask this... while the question is interesting, *I don't think it's useful for anyone else except the OP*.

Comment: @dda, what a disease can possibly let you fly 6 hours but not more? 6 sounds quiet long already.

Comment: No idea. But I wasn't exactly going to ask my boss about his medical history. And his daughter has the same disease, while the son doesn't.

Comment: If anything happened that caused the flight to last more than 2 hours, would it be a problem?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie we have plenty of purely theoretical questions on this site. I'm willing to bet OP doesn't really plan to do a 17-segment flight to Tokyo :)

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm okay with theoretical questions, provided that there's an underlying background. Now that this question seems to be accepted well in this community, can we ask similar questions with different duration and/or location?

Comment: @AndrewT. the only way to find out is to post your question and see if it's closed by the community :)

Comment: @JonathanReez I've no problem with a theoretical question :) but the practical aspects of this are no longer relevant if it's only theoretical. If it's for a real situation, we would want to talk about those other aspects, too.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing this, say, replacing "London" with "New York".  It looks like you can get pretty far in Alaska and in Arctic Canada.  Heading south, I can make it as far as Quito (say, Newark - Charlotte - Atlanta - New Orleans - Cancun - San Salvador - San Jose - Panama City - Bogota - Quito) but it doesn't appear from flightconnections.com that you can short hop across the Amazon.  Connections to Europe are impossible because there are no flights from Canada (Arctic or otherwise) to Greenland.

Answer (score 41):

[FlightConnections.com](http://www.flightconnections.com) lists flight times rounded off to the nearest 5 minutes.  Limiting oneself to connections listed on this website as having a flight time of 2h00m or less (as of December 2017), one can construct the following 17-segment itinerary from London to Tokyo, via Shanghai:

- London–Frankfurt:  1h40m
- Frankfurt–Belgrade:  1h50m
- Belgrade–Istanbul: 1h45m
- Istanbul–Beirut: 1h50m
- Beirut–Baghdad: 1h30m
- Baghdad–Bahrain: 1h50m
- Bahrain–Muscat: 1h30m
- Muscat–Karachi: 1h55m
- Karachi–Lahore: 1h45m
- Lahore–Delhi: 1h25m
- Delhi–Kathmandu: 1h35m
- Kathmandu–Lhasa: 1h25m
- Lhasa–Chengdu: 2h00m
- Chengdu–Changsha: 1h50m
- Changsha–Shanghai: 2h00m
- Shanghai–Fukuoka: 1h25m
- Fukuoka–Tokyo: 1h45m

It also appears to be possible to make it to Sydney in 27 segments. Proceed to Chengdu as above, then:

- Chengdu–Kunming: 1h30m
- Kunming–Hanoi: 1h25m
- Hanoi–Phnom Penh: 1h40m
- Phnom Penh–Kuala Lumpur: 1h50m
- Kuala Lumpur–Jakarta: 2h00m
- Jakarta–Surabaya:  1h15m
- Surabaya–Denpasar:  1h10m
- Denapasar–Dili:  1h45m
- Dili–Darwin: 1h20m
- Darwin–Gove: 1h40m
- Gove–Cairns: 1h45m
- Cairns–Townsville: 0h55m
- Townsville–Brisbane: 1h50m
- Brisbane–Sydney: 1h35m

Finally, London–Cape Town can be done in 15 segments.  Proceed to Belgrade as above, and then take the following flights:

- Belgrade–Athens:  1h30m
- Athens–Cairo: 1h50m
- Cairo–Medina: 1h50m
- Medina–Khartoum: 2h00m
- Khartoum–Juba: 1h00m (though I suspect that this should be 2h00m, given that the return flight is 3h00m)
- Juba–Nairobi:  1h40m
- Nairobi–Dar es Salaam:  1h25m
- Dar es Salaam–Pemba:  1h10m
- Pemba–Nampula: 0h40m
- Nampula–Beira: 1h15m
- Beira–Johannesburg: 1h50m
- Johannesburg–Bloemfontein: 1h05m
- Bloemfontein–Cape Town: 1h40m

Given the inefficiency of the route I found through Mozambique, there may be a route to Cape Town with fewer segments via western Africa rather than eastern Africa.

[image: map by jcaron on gcmap see comment below]

All of these itineraries are presented with the caveat that I have not verified the flight times with the airlines in question;  indeed, I am not 100% convinced that Flightconnections.com is handling the time zones correctly for some of the flights in Africa.

Comment: Just reading these lists makes my sinuses ache.

Comment: Hobart is further from London than Sydney, and is likely the "furthest" such place on the planet unless you can find a way to get to NZ which I doubt is possible.

Comment: I can get to Greenland via LHR -> EDI -> FAE -> RKV -> KUS -> GOH, but there don't appear to be any connections to Canada, which puts the Falkland Islands out of reach.

Comment: Just for fun, the 3 routes above mapped: http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LON-FRA-BEG-IST-BEY-BGW-BAH-MCT-KHI-LHE-DEL-KTM-LXA-CTU-CSX-PVG-FUK-TYO,+LON-FRA-BEG-IST-BEY-BGW-BAH-MCT-KHI-LHE-DEL-KTM-LXA-CTU-KMG-HAN-PNH-KUL-CGK-SUB-DPS-DIL-DRW-GOV-CNS-TSV-BNE-SYD,+LON-FRA-BEG-ATH-CAI-MED-KRT-JUB-NBO-DAR-POL-APL-BEW-JNB-BFN-CPT

Comment: We should also remember than once upon a time, that was how long distance travel was done. Some of the legs in this post are actually slightly longer than the operating range of the de Havilland D.H.86 which was used on the Singapore-Sydney part of the Kangaroo route at its inception.

Comment: Just for correctness, it was Singapore-Brisbane, and it wasn't called the Kangaroo Route yet in 1935. But the whole London-Brisbane trip did make quite a few stops en route...

Comment: @Doc If you go soon enough, it might actually be possible. ANZ operates flights from BNE to NLK (Norfolk Island) and, until Jan 14, 2018, there's also scheduled service from NLK on to AKL. Granted, BNE-NLK is pushing the limits of 2 hours, but it can be done. The average seems to be a bit higher than 2 hours, though.

Comment: @MikeHarris I know that feeling all too well. I get a terrible pain in one of mine whenever I am landing unless I consume hard candies all the way down. Usually my sinus will inform me that we are descending a couple of minutes before the crew make the announcement.

Comment: @jcaron I've edited in your map from the link, it really helps show what's happening